# PDF compressor software to host on your own server

Tags: open-source, pdf, self-hosted, file-compression

**Goal**

A web-based open source software to compress PDF files, to submit files via a browser, but to install on my own Linux server and use its processing power.

**Requirements**

- A web interface. A command line software is acceptable as a last option because I can develop the web frontend, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.
- Linux compatible, regardless of the programming language.
- Be able install it on my own server.

**What I already know and found**

- [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/): Linux compatible, I can install on my own server and it's open source. **Obviously**, since it is only a command line software, web interface is a feature that I will have to develop apart. *(my best option, so far)*
- [3-Heights PDF Optimizer](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/pdf-optimization-reduce-size.aspx): Linux compatible, I can install on my own server, doesn't include a web interface but offers an API. **Same cons from Ghostscript** and it is not open source. *(used in [smallpdf.com](http://smallpdf.com/))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [pdftk server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/):

### Pros

- Runs on Linux, OS-X & Windows
- Can do a lot of pdf manipulations including Uncompress and Re-Compress Page Streams

### Cons

- Command Line
- Not Open Source but from the web site:

> If you plan to distribute PDFtk Server as part of your own software, you will need a PDFtk Server Redistribution License. The exception to this rule is if your software is licensed to the public under the GPL or another compatible license.

Comment: Choosing this answer since it is the only one.